# number of prime number below 1000 in Rstudio

Tags: r

I would like to find the number of prime number below 1000 with Rstudio.
I've wrote previously a function (`is.prime` which tell us if a number is prime or not (`TRUE` or `FALSE`)) and now i would like to write some line to find the number of prime below 1000. Below is what I found but it doesn't work:

```
k=0

for(i in 1:1000){

    if(is.prime(i)==TRUE){
        k=k+1
    }

}
```

If someone have an idea, I would really appreciate.

Comment: First step would be to fix the syntax error (wrong position of `)`) in the `if` construct.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? A warning? The wrong answer? (how do you know it's wrong?) Now that the syntax error is fixed, do you think the problem is in your loop or in `is.prime`?

Comment: I want the function to return the number of prime below 1000 but there is an error with "=="

Comment: Can you post the actual text of the error? Edit it into your question. If `is.prime` always returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, then you shouldn't *need* the `== TRUE`, because `if(TRUE)` is the same as `if(TRUE == TRUE)`, but it shouldn't hurt anything to have it. I'd recommend, inside the loop, before the `if()`, adding some print statements: `print(i)` and `print(is.prime(i))`. This will help you find the problem.

Comment: `k <- 0; for(i in 1:1000) k <- k + is.prime(i)` Or `sum(sapply(1:1000, is.prime))`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little strange (it's the second about the same problem) and i'll try to help you without giving any *functional* code. How?

First we need to plan the steps about the problem:

1. We need to create a function in R that returs if a giving input is or not a prime number.

   ```
   is_prime = function(my_number) {
       # Logic behind prime numbers
       # A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers. (wiki)
   }
   ```

The function *is_prime* must return a boolean value (or array, based on the input)

2. We need to filter the prime numbers.

   ```
   number_sequence = 1:1000 # it's an array
   is_prime_vector = is_prime(number_sequence) # so, the function will return an array too.
   prime_numbers = number_sequence[is_prime_vector]
   ```

I hope this can help you.